# Going back to sending intent activity in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to figure out a way to go back to the sending activity from an activity that could have multiple incoming activities, here is my scenario:

Suppose i'm on activity A and I send someone to activity C (you can get to activity C from multiple activities).  On button click in activity C, I want to send user back to activity A.

How would I go about doing that?

I've tried the below and different variations with no luck, any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

```
mGoBackToActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String goToClass = incomingGameIntent.getStringExtra("activity");

        Intent goBacktoActivity = null;
        try {
            goBacktoActivity = new Intent(Searched_Game_ListView.this, Class.forName(goToClass));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        startActivity(goBacktoActivity);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the user is done with activity C and you want him to return to activity A, you should use the `finish()` method on activity C. You can even use this to pass a "result" of the current activity.

Comment: Thanks Bert, how do I get back to Activity A though?

Comment: If you call `finish()`, you end up at the activity you came from. Isn't that what you asked for? If not, please clarify.

Comment: Sorry Bert you are correct.  I also found a different way that I am going to post, but i'd still like to know how to use finish().  How would I call finish()?

Comment: You could call `activity.finish();`, where activity is a reference to activity C. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()

Answer (score 0):

Bert's answer above works perfectly.  I also was able to get it working with the code below:

```
mGoBackToActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This works, because the default implementation of `onBackPressed()` calls `finish()`. Good work though.